# $timeout.flush() is not working

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I trying to test changes after `$timeout`, here is it:

```
it('after timeout', function () {
        expect(scope.Vm.isLoaded).toBe(true);
        $timeout.flush(10);
        $timeout.flush(2000);
        $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();
        expect(scope.Vm.isLoaded).toBe(false);
      });
```

this is not working
on checking `$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();`
I have error:

> Error: Deferred tasks to flush (2): {id: 0, time: 0}, {id: 1, time:
>   2000}

after that I added :

```
$timeout.flush(10);
```

result is:

> Error: Deferred tasks to flush (1): {id: 1, time: 2000}

when added:

```
$timeout.flush(10);
$timeout.flush(2000);
```

test is failed, looks like it's not working, what I missing? any ideas?

Comment: try this link
 https://gist.github.com/bbraithwaite/5a5b817895db75250ea6

Comment: @Kasiriveni, thank's, I using almost the same way, except, instead of `sumWithWait` function I have `$rootScope.$on` event, and run timeout inside it

Comment: I use $rootScope.$digest(); $timeout.flush(); can you add the section you are trying to test?

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to help you because at first you didn't show the code you try to test. We don't know why your testing code has two timeouts.

The second one is the Angular JS had an issue with verifyNoPendingTasks() that was described in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14336

And it was resolved in commit https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6f7674a7d063d434205f75f5b861f167e8125999 on Jun 27 after you create this issue.

So, I believe if you update the AngularJS dependencies you could get the right working $verifyNoPendingTasks method.